# Getting file from URL that triggers a download in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I have a URL in a web analytics reporting platform that basically triggers a download/export of the report you're looking at. The downloaded file itself is a CSV, and the link that triggers the download uses several attached parameters to define things like the fields in the report. What I am looking to do is download the CSV that the link triggers a download of.

I'm using Python 3.6, and I've been told that the server I'll be deploying on does not support Selenium or any webkits like PhantomJS. Has anyone successfully accomplished this?

Comment: Why can't you just save the URL of the file and then request it directly?

Comment: When you do something like element.click() with Selenium, the client machine is the target of the download. So the file should end up in your Downloads folder. The server does not need to have Selenium installed on it (unless it is also the client machine).

Answer (score 0):

If the file is a CSV file, you might want to consider downloading it's content directly, by using the requests module, something like this.

```
import requests
session=requests.Session()
information=session.get(#the link of the page here)
```

Then You can decode the information and read the contents as you wish using the CSV module, something like this (the csv module should be imported):

```
decoded_information=information.content.decode('utf-8')
data=decoded_information.splitlines()
data=csv.DictReader(data)
```

You can use a for loop to access each row in the data as you wish using the column headings as dictionary keys like so:

```
for row in data:
itemdate=row['Date']
...
```

Or you can save the decoded contents by writing them to a file with something like this:

```
decoded_information=information.content.decode('utf-8')
file=open("filename.csv", "w")
file.write(decoded_information)
file.close
```

A couple of links with documentation on the CSV module is provided here just in case you haven't used it before:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html
http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/using-the-csv-module-in-python/

Hope this helps!